# PAM cracklib vs login.defs

Tags: linux, security, authentication, password, pam

If there are different parameters set for minimum password length in pam_cracklib and login.defs. Which takes precedence ?

Any good docs/books about PAM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the man page, `login.defs` is no longer used by `login`, `su`, `passwd`, etc (see `login.defs(5)`) unless you use `pam_pwcheck`.